# Route Data in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have a razor page call "app" in the default Pages folder.

I can view this page just fine with `http://myapp.com/app`

Now I want to add a route parameter so the url looks like this:
`http:/myapp.com/app/greg`

I want to extract `greg` from the URL and use it in the page.

So I tried this:

```
HttpGet("app/{name}")]
public void OnGet(string name)
{
    //Do something with name.
}
```

But I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems attribute routing is not supported in Razor Pages. This ended up working for me.

app.cshtml:

```
@page "{name}"
```

app.cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string Name{ get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
     //Do something with this.Name...
}
```

The page directive creates the route and the BindProperty attribute binds the value to the property.

If you want to get the value from the query string instead, change `@page "{name}"` to just `@page`